# How to global import my own DLog macros without use pch file

Tags: ios, macros

I wrote my own macros to output detail message in development environment

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define GCLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define GCLog(...);
```

I don't want to import this in every file, and I know the shortcoming of PCH file.
So what can I do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got four options:

1. Import some file containing that macro in every file you want to use
   it in
2. Put it in the PCH which is automatically imported for you
3. Put it in a file and import that file in the PCH
4. Include that macro in every file you want to use it (generally a bad plan)

Personally when I was writing Objective-C, I would go with option 2 when I wanted something available in every file.